# Inconsistent string length definition between Java String.substring() and Oracle 11g column VARCHAR2 size

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

I set up my database with a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t_audit_log
(
  description VARCHAR2 (2500)
);
```

In the Java app which uses it, I employ Hibernate to map a data class onto it and to make sure that I'm not going to generate SQLExceptions, I put this truncation algorithm in the property getter:

```
private static final int MAX_STRING_LEN_2500 = 2499;

public void setDescription(final String newDescription) {
    if (newDescription != null
        && newDescription.length() > MAX_STRING_LEN_2500) {
        description = newDescription.substring(0, MAX_STRING_LEN_2500);
    } else {
        description = newDescription;
    }
}
```

For thousands of audit log entries, this worked fine - until today. I found this in the logs:

```
Nov 09, 2015 7:54:40 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 12899, SQLState: 72000
Nov 09, 2015 7:54:40 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-12899: value too large for column "BLABLA"."T_AUDIT_LOG"."DESCRIPTION" 
    (actual: 2501, maximum: 2500)
```

Why has `substring()` left an extra character in the value?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the only one place that set the description field?

Comment: besides, `MAX_STRING_LEN_2500 = 2499` is giving away one character...

Comment: @JorgeCampos I deduce that `substring` is causing the error because the string that is truncated is about 5000 characters, and the error says `(actual: 2501, maximum: 2500)` not `(actual: 5000, maximum: 2500)`

Comment: Well, it's the wrong conclusion. The string is truncated properly to 2499 characters, but one or two of the characters are longer than one byte, so what's being passed to Oracles is 2501 bytes.

Comment: Exacly what @RealSkeptic said. Add to your log the number of bytes of your string then you will see that the answers provided solve your problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic the string is truncated to 2500 characters - `substring`'s parameters are [`beginIndex, endIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) but your second assertion sounds like the answer. How can I control that?

Comment: `substring`'s `endIndex` is *exclusive*, read the documentation carefully. Anyway, the answers are correct - you should set the column limit to characters. The number of bytes depends on the encoding and the particular characters (UTF-8 can take up to 6 bytes per character), so controlling it on the Java side is going to be hard. Note also that Oracle allows only 4000 bytes, which means that a value with 2500 characters, 2000 of which take more than 1 byte, will exceed that limit despite a definition of `VARCHAR2(2500 char)`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic good catch re endIndex. So what I need to do is work out what the maximum size of a character is. If I increase my column size to 4000 bytes, then I set my Java substring endIndex to  `4000 / max` Are you saying max = 6? JonSkeet's answer refers to UTF-16 in Java, rather than UTF-8.

Comment: The question is the database encoding, not the Java string encoding. If it's UTF-16, then it's exactly two bytes per `char`. If it's UTF-8, it will be one byte for ASCII characters, but will be a different length for different characters.

Answer (score 10):

I *suspect* your database settings are set to use ["byte semantics"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1835) for the length operations (which is the default for `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`), in which case you're saying you want the field to be up to 2500 bytes in length when encoded, not 2500 characters. Suppose your database is using UTF-8 to encode the string - if your string has 2498 ASCII characters and 1 character of U+20A0 (the Euro symbol), that would result in a total of 2501 bytes, but only 2499 characters.

The Java `length()` and `substring()` operations will operate in terms of UTF-16 code units - which may or may not *quite* align with "character semantics". (It's somewhat unlikely that you'll be trying to store characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, which is where a single character takes two UTF-16 code units, but it's possible.)

You really need to work out what you want the field length to *actually* be represented in - then you can work out whether to change how you're performing the truncation in Java.

Comment: This looks like the answer - but to be absolutely robust, can you say how I should find out what the database character encoding is, and how to set it. I'll have to set it up if it's not right - along with NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS.

Comment: @Adam: I would be looking at the documentation myself, to be honest. Start with the link in my answer, and there are plenty of links within that documentation.

Comment: Originally we had intended to keep the database free of the data that the app processes, but here in this audit log table, examples of the data have crept in. It could be Japanese, Chinese, Korean - literally anything. I'm not familiar with the term "Basic Multilingual Plane" but I assume that excludes those character sets.

Comment: @Adam: I wouldn't assume that :) I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane for starters. Do you need to store emoji? I believe they're the most likely non-BMP characters you'll run into.

Answer (score 7):

Revise your Oracle NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS, you don´t specify if you are using BYTE or CHAR, defaults is BYTE. Some characters may need mor than one byte to store into database, so try to modify you table to

```
CREATE TABLE t_audit_log
(
  description VARCHAR2 (2500 char)
);
```

and try again.

---

From [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e24448/initparams149.htm):

> The session-level value of NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS specifies the default
>   length semantics to use for VARCHAR2 and CHAR table columns,
>   user-defined object attributes, and PL/SQL variables in database
>   objects created in the session. **This default may be overridden by the
>   explicit length semantics qualifiers BYTE and CHAR in column,
>   attribute, and variable definitions**.

Comment: @Adam: This is best answer, IMHO. Try this and I think things will work for you. You can create a simple POJO + demo table, to first reproduce and then test the fix.

Comment: I have added a official word from Oracle docs to your answer, I hope you are fine with it. Let me know in case you think otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer with documentation, now is better :D